# How to update the weights knowing the loss in Neural Network

Tags: stochastic-processes, gradient-descent, neural-networks

## Question

How update the weight knowing the loss

## Work explanation

I have a really simple network composed by two layers with one neurons in both layers.

[image]

Considering an input of **1**, the final result of this NN is **0.50** and the expected is 1

Now to train this simple NN I've calculated the loss following the reasoning explained in this video: https://youtu.be/Zr5viAZGndE?t=729

[image]

As you can see the loss is **-0.249** and I know that lowering this error mean get  a result near the expected.

The problem that I'm encountering is how to update the the weight of **0.03** to something that let the Neural Network lower the loss and outputs 1 as result on the next iteration.

Comment: The general answer is matrix multiplication everywhere. Simpler answer is to make sure you're reading a good source on this (e.g., a textbook or class notes or the like) and not some dude's project thrown onto the interwebs. Haven't checked in this case, but make sure you are actually understanding all the math!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen thanks for the answer. This math seems resonable, the only thing that I can't understand is how the loss affect the weights. Do you have a good source that explain the back propagation and gradient descent that I can read?

Comment: are you familiar with multivariable calculus? It's generally a lot of applications of the chain rule. Backpropogation is basically "apply the chain rule over and over to push the variable differentiating all the way up the chain of layers"

Comment: Not really I'm doing a search about it. But what's the most used approach to do the back propagation if there are a lot of way to do it?

Comment: if you don't know multivariable calculus, you'll have difficulty understanding any of the math. You might be able to understand a single layer, e.g. using the derivation on the Wikipedia page on Backpropogation. There really aren't a ton of different variations of backpropogation in my experience, it's more like there are a lot of *alternatives* (there are some differences, like the choice of activation function). Gradient descent is more interesting in my opinion because of things like batch gradient descent, stochastic gradient descent, momentums, etc.

Comment: My best recommendation for building a neural network if you don't know the necessary math is, 1) ideally learn the math and understand what's happening, or 2) skip right to using Torch or TensorFlow or the like, which hide the math from an end-user. Pretty much everyone ends up using a well-built library for building a NN anyway, but knowing how it works can be beneficial both for understanding and for modifying things beyond what your chosen NN library is doing

Comment: You are giving me golden information, So I'm going to study multivariable calculus thank you a lot, to be fair I want to learn how NN works rather use a random library and for doing it I'm building a library from the scratch. What I did until now is Forward propagation (so nothing special yet). https://github.com/AndreaCatania/brain

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :) for easy sources of multivariable notes, I've found Paul's Notes online to be quite useful. YouTube will also have a lot of good videos... In particular, I'd check out Welch Lab's series on "Neural Networks Demystified" (which actually goes through and explains the math to a beginner audience! Also see his machine learning series) and maybe 3Blue1Brown's series on Neural Networks (I only saw a bit, but I  generally find the channel pretty good at visually explaining things). I'd focus largely on understanding the multivariable chain rule.

Comment: After going through those videos to get a rough idea of what's happening and at least skimming through Paul's notes (at least through the end of his discussions on the chain rule) you'll be fairly prepped to read more in-depth chain rule calculations. You might want to pick up a book on multivariable calc from a library to help deepen understanding and/or search the internet for more help, but that should get you started. Once you've done all that, you can search for derivations/proofs of backpropogation online and hopefully understand a decent amount of it. Let me know if you have questions!

Comment: Really appreciated! Thanks Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some studies I understood that the **loss** calculated with the above formula is the delta weight that can be directly added to the weight.

Initially I got confused because the problem of this formula was the first term of the chain rule where the inputs are inverted and the adjustment was going in the opposite direction.

So the correct is `2(expected - gussed)(sig'(input))(input)(learning rate)`